# Passing hidden input value from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to generate an excel file when a link is clicked without being redirected anywhere. I make it into the servlet but when I try to get the value of a hidden input, I get a null pointer exception. The code I'm using is

JSP

```
<html:form action="/UploadExcel.do" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<a href="#" onclick="ExcelFiller.fill">Download Excel</a>
<input type="hidden" name="refBgcId" id="refBgcId" value="84"></input>
</html:form>
```

Servlet

```
public class ExcelFiller extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {    
    super.init(config);
}

public void destroy() {

}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Made it to the servlet");
    doPost(request,response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("In doPost");
    HttpSession session=(HttpSession) request.getSession(false);

    String loggedInUserId = (String)session.getAttribute("strUserId");
    try{
        String referenceid = request.getParameter("refBgcId").toString();/*NULL POINTER EXCEPTION*/
        ArrayList<String> details = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        details = UploadBGCDAO.getDetails(referenceid);
        createExcel(request,response,details, loggedInUserId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I have tried finding the solution in the answers to similar questions on this site but I still can't make this work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass parameters in URL in Java Script as :

```
var refBgcId=84;
var url = "/UploadExcel.do?refBgcId="+refBgcId;
window.location.href =url;
```

and in servlet you can access as

```
   String refBgcId= request.getParameter("refBgcId").toString();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that redirect me somewhere?

Comment: Well I'll be damned! I tweaked the code you gave to open in a new tab and it worked!

Comment: @Prashant doesn't this make the parameter open, because Amber wanted to hide the parameter . If I am wrong kindly correct me.

Comment: @saikumar : whatever you are saying is correct, but he wanted to access the variable from JSP without submitting the from..

Answer (score 3):

Input parameter will be passed to the servlet only when you submit a form, not when your anchor tag is clicked.

If you want to pass a parameter append the parameter in a query String.

Comment: "Input parameter will be passed to the servlet only when you submit a form".  Thx. :D

Comment: @tomyforever No worries, mate.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="ExcelFiller.fill">
<input type="hidden" name="refBgcId" id="refBgcId" value="84"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Download Excel"></input>
</form>
```

and in the servlet make the following changes.
the name of the attribute is `refBgcId`.
change the statement

`String referenceid = request.getParameter("ref_id").toString();`

to

`String referenceid = request.getParameter("refBgcId").toString();`

Comment: I replaced the ref_id with refBgcId but it still doesn't work. I also edited the question to include the form tag in the jsp part. I cannot change the form's action....

Answer (score 0):

String referenceid = request.getParameter("refBgcId").toString(); // here refBgcId is a name...dont confuse with name and Id pass name from jsp

and then in servlet try this

String referenceid = request.getParameter("refBgcId").toString();